# Format time in ISO 8601 on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, nsdate

How do I get the current time and format it to ISO 8601?

By these I mean the format: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ where T and Z are not time represented; they are constants.

Answer (score 0):

The way to achieve this is by:

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'"];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```